# RSpec: should have_content can't find text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I have the following page

```
<ul class="account_menu dropdown-menu">
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="current"><span>My account</span></li>
    <li class="account"><a href="#">account-1 (Editor)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Testing it with Cucumber using this step

```
within(scope) do
    page.should have_content(content)
end
```

Test passes when content = 'account-1' and fails with content = 'My account'. Scope is both cases is 'account_menu'

```
And he should see "My account" within account menu

expected to find text "My account" in "My Accountaccount-1 (Editor)"
(RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

- rails 3.2.17
- rspec-rails 2.14.1
- capybara 2.1.0

Why it can't find 'My account' text? Thanks

Comment: You're using `within(scope)`; what scope are you applying?

Comment: scope is account_menu

Comment: capitalization? the "A" in account is capitalized in the page and not in your test. I don't think the default regex is case insensitive, so it's not matching.

Comment: in both test and in the page its 'My account'

Comment: I can clearly see "My account" in "My Accountaccount-1 (Editor)" - from the error message - though RSpec for some reason can't

Comment: Show exact and complete test you have. Asking 'why it works wrong when I have all correct' will not take you far.

Answer (score 4):

`have_content` sometimes ends up concatenating content in unexpected ways. In your case

```
<li class="current"><span>My account</span></li>
<li class="account"><a href="#">account-1 (Editor)</a></li>
```

Becomes "My Accountaccount-1 (Editor)"

If you try

```
expect("My Accountaccount-1 (Editor)").to have_content("My account")
```

It will also fail which is technically correct since "My account " is not in the string. The alternative is to use the `match` matcher or test for the concatenated string (ugly).